# Ember.js deleteRecord() in Controller not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

First I am using `ember.js 1.0.0`, `ember-data 1.0.0 b3` with the `DS.RESTAdapter`.

Creating works fine so far, but if I try to delete a record (got it straight from the Getting Started) I receive the following Error Message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'deleteRecord'`

This is my template:

```
   {{#each}}
   {{#link-to "role" this classBinding="isLoading:is-loading" tag="tr" }}
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
        <td>{{ role }}</td>
        <td><button {{ action "deleteRoleAction" this}}>[x]</button></td>
   {{/link-to}}
   {{/each}}
```

and this is the action (in the controller)

```
this.get('model').deleteRecord()
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how your controller's model property was assigned, it's hard to say why that object wouldn't respond to `deleteRecord`. But it looks like what you're doing is iterating over the controller's content (presumably, a collection) and then passing the individual models to the action (`{{action "deleteRoleAction" this}}`). So you probably want your action to look like this:

```
deleteRoleAction: function(role) {
  role.deleteRecord();
}
```

Note that `deleteRecord` by itself only sets the deleted flag on the model; if you actually want to save that delete to your server, you need to call `role.save();` too. (There is also a new `destroyRecord` method in 1.0.0.b4 that does both.)

Comment: Thanks. This is solving my problem. The thing though is, that the getting started is doing it the way I was doing it and it worked there.

Comment: That's because they set up a new itemController for each Todo item: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/